# Floodlight mounting questions for outside - what to do?

Tags: electrical, vinyl

I am currently trying to mount a floodlight outside on top of my vinyl siding. I have a "triple three mount" and a metal electrical box to go behind it. Is this a good way to do it, or is there a better electrical box I should be using? I am concerned about the holes in the electrical box. I could always fill them in with outdoor caulking to make sure nothing gets in. Right now it looks like I could screw in the electrical box, then place the triple three mount on top of it, and the pressure from the floodlight being installed would keep the triple three mount in place. Looking for suggestions.

[image]

Comment: what's a `triple three mount`?

Comment: @jsotola - The clay colored mount that goes over top triple three vinyl siding - i.imgur.com/3hOkzOx.png

Answer (score 2):

Your plan is good.  The holes in the box are for mounting screws. You could caulk the unused holes, but it isn't critical.

Be sure to use a cable strain relief , such as the [Halex](https://www.homedepot.com/p/3-8-in-Standard-Fitting-Non-Metallic-Push-In-Connector-10-Pack-27500/203803776?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RKT-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_THRIFTTRAD-71700000110012104-58700008378060397-92700076247463580&gad_source=1&gclid=CjwKCAiA6byqBhAWEiwAnGCA4FfpNuKYUe2ZmHdDLPfhzvq-DJ2sv09wOyx5tfqRkc7cQoC8f5v3jRoChhIQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) to insulate and hold the cable going into the box.

Comment: I would also consider a layer of weatherstripping foam around the edge of the "box" and possibly a U-shape between the top of the mount and the siding.

Comment: @Huesmann 1. You're talking about where the metal box touches the vinyl mount right? Is there a good way to run weather stripping since it's a circle? Or just cut lots of little pieces to put it into a circle? 2. And for the mount you want me to also put weather stripping where the vinyl mount will touch the side of my house, but in a U shape so water can run off - correct?

Comment: The weatherstripping may or may not be needed depending on how open to the elements the light fixture is.

Comment: @Aaron yes, the edge of the box.  The self-adhesive foam rubber tape is very flexible, no need to cut sections.  For the mount, it would be an upside down U—across the top, and down the sides (leave the bottom open).

Comment: @Huesmann 1. I guess I could do a square shape of that on the inside of the vinyl mount, then press the metal electrical box up against that, right? 2. As far as putting this on the outside of the vinyl box, is there a way to make it not poke out the sides and expose to sun? Also, is there any kind you recommend or should I just look up "self-adhesive foam rubber tape" and use that for both inside the vinyl mount and around it in that U shape?

Comment: Well, you can get the tape in white.  As to square, not sure why you'd want a square tape shape and round box.

Comment: @Huesmann Do they sell it in round? I couldn't find anything at home depot that was like a foam rubber tape and round. It was just on a roll. What tape were you thinking? Can you send a link so I can see what you mean?

Comment: Yes, it's on a roll.  You just bend the tape around in a circle.  Get the narrowest you can—it'll be easier to "bend."